# Determine list view item position in the list view with y coordinate

Tags: android, listview, ontouchlistener, motionevent

Given a y-coordinate obtained by `onTouch` on a `ListView` object, how could you determine the position/index that touched item has based on  `motionEvent.getY()`?

I can't use `onItemClickListener` unfortunately.

```
getListView().setOnTouchListener(listViewTouchListener);

View.OnTouchListener listViewTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.d("test", "Y pos: " + motionEvent.getY());
        }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have the `MotionEvent` object available, you can do something like

```
private ListView list;

<some code to initialize ListView>

public int getPosition(MotionEvent e1){ 
    int pos = list.pointToPosition((int)e1.getX(), (int)e1.getY()); 
    Log.d("test","Position: "+pos);
    return pos; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Heskja . this is really helpful.